# Choose Worksheet based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 365. 
I am trying to copy a sheet from a template in "Tournament Master Format 36.xls" (All tabs are numbers based on how many teams are in the bracket) based on the number of teams from ThisWorkbook sheet Data, Cell K4.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim Size As String

    Size = "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("K4")"

    Workbooks("Tournament Master Format 36.xls").Sheets(Size).Range("A1:AO311").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1") 

End Sub
```

Updated Code:

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim Size As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim SheetNum As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Workbooks("Scheduling Test Template.xlsx").Sheets("Data").Activate

For i = 2 To 10
    'Size = Cells(i, 11).Value
    Size = CStr(Workbooks("Scheduling Test 
    Template.xlsx").Sheets("Data").Range("K4").Value)

    'SheetNum = CStr(Cells(i, 10)) + " & Under"
    SheetNum = i
    Debug.Print Size

    If Size > 0 Then
        Set ws = 

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = SheetNum

        Workbooks("Tournament Master Format 36.xls").Sheets(Size)
        .Range("A1:AO311").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNum).Range ("A1")
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You dont want to put `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("K4")` inside of quotes - it becomes a literal string then instead of the value of the objects that you want. Frankly, i'm surprised it even compiles like that.

Comment: Im very new to VBA coding so im probably doing everything wrong. I some changes. If I set Size to " Range("K4").Value" would it work? I keep getting a Subscript out of Range error

Comment: I took away the quotes and its still giving me a Subscript out of Range Error

Comment: I think thats it. When I step through once I get to Size it still has a value of 0, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation, but try using `Debug.Print Size` and see if this is the correct value of Size. If it is the correct value, now check whether there exists a sheet with the same value as `Size`.

Also, I would recommend against using `.Activate` and instead using:

```
Size = Workbooks("Scheduling Test Template.xlsx").Sheets("Data").Range("K4").Value
```

Ps. If you comment under this answer, I will be able to join the conversation with you and braX.

Comment: I got it to set a Size but its gave me a Subscript out of Range Error on the last line

Comment: Comment out the `Workbooks("Tournament Master Format 36.xls").Sheets("Size").Range("A1:AO311").Copy_ 
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range ("A1")` line and try `Debug.Print Size` to see the value of Size

Comment: Where is it supposed to print? The code ran and nothing happened

Comment: In the VBA Editor, go to View > Immediate Window, and once you see the Immediate Window, run the code again.

Comment: got it. It returned 20, which is what its supposed to be

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want to copy cells from a sheet called 20? Or is the 20 referring to the index (position) of the sheet?

Comment: Since we have defined Size as being a String, it's looking for a sheet named 20, not the sheet with an index of 20.

Comment: The Sheet name is 20. When I replace "Size" with "20" it works

Comment: ok, then use `Size = CStr(Workbooks("Scheduling Test Template.xlsx").Sheets("Data").Range("K4").Value)`

Comment: It copied the sheet for 14 (20th sheet)

Comment: Okay, first do `Dim Size as String`, then `Workbooks("Tournament Master Format 36.xls").Sheets(Size & "").Range("A1:AO311").Copy_` etc, and try it with and without the `CStr` code I suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: Error saying "Object doesnt Support this Property or Method"

Comment: Try it with only `Sheets(Size)` instead of `Sheets(Size & "")`. It's so weird one of these should definitely work. Also which line is throwing an error?

Comment: Same Error. Its that last line still. I made some changes to the code so it will loop through several sizes, Ill edit the original post so you can see if something there is messing it up

Comment: Its Updated Now

Comment: Yeah to be honest I don't see what may be going wrong, can you confirm that inputting "20" instead of Size still works?

Comment: Wait if Size is a String, you can't check `If Size > 0`

Comment: I commented out the If Statement. I replaced size with "20" and it gave me the same error this time. I dont understand its the same as it was before now?

Comment: So I got rid of the _ after Copy and put it all on the same line and it worked.

Comment: Okay that's sweet!

Comment: Would love it if you could mark this answer as being the best answer if this has been helpful. I'll finally get enough Reputation to comment on the question and others' answers hahaha

Comment: Sure Thing! Thanks for the help

Comment: So everything with that is working fine. But now I have a new Problem. the original workbook has all the templates in it. One of the formulas in the template is supposed to use data from one of the sheets once its copied to the second workbook. but onec its in the second workbook but it trys to point to the original workbook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203569/discussion-between-puravthegreat-and-spenser1235yahoocom).